# One Box body text is invisible

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, chat

In chat the body text is now white, but the One Box background is also white, yielding the below:

[image]

The box text is invisible, but if you try to select it you can see it's still there, it's just white-on-white.

Comment: I guess it kinda solves the spoiler problem we were having... I guess :/

Comment: In addition, when you follow a ping link to chat (i.e. when someone @ mentions you and you click the dropdown in the top left of the screen on the main site then click on the chat mention there), the chat with the @mention is white on white.

Comment: Please remember to tag questions about chat as such. Thanks!

Comment: @Keen: I'm not sure what you mean; if you mean the white on yellow of the message highlighted in the transcript, that's now fixed. Otherwise, can you explain more what you mean?

Comment: @balpha Yeah, the white on yellow.  Sorry, I failed to take a screenshot so I misremembered the colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed; it's black on white as expected now.